# Transparent proxying through a TAP interface

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, proxy

Say we have machine A, a recent Linux machine. And machine B, a machine whose traffic we want to proxy transparently. I'm a bit clueless on how to achieve this so please bear with me. Here's my take on it:

- Change the default gateway on machine B to be machine A's LAN IP address.
- Create a TAP interface, let's call it `tap0`, on machine A, that's connected to the Internet via this machine's WiFi/Ethernet interface, let's call it `eth0`. I'm guessing this would be achieved by assigning an IP address to `tap0` and setting its default gateway to be that of `eth0`.
- Set up iptables rules, inspired by those in [mitmproxy's docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/) so that inbound traffic on `eth0` will be routed to `tap0`.
- `tcpdump` the traffic on `tap0`.

Would this setup work, and what are the configs needed to:
A) Have an Internet connection on `tap0`.
B) Route inbound traffic on `eth0` to `tap0`.

Comment: A tap interface is connected to a *process* (like QEMU for a VM). So your 2nd bullet is not clear at all. Can you clarify?

Comment: Again, you assume you need a tap interface, but you don't appear to understand what is a tap interface intended for. Can you clarify? If machine A has only one actual interface, are you intending it to use it as a one-armed router or what else?